# Use local webserver or use Git

Tags: apache-http-server, git, webserver

We are a starting company of 2 people and we are debating if we are going to use a local webserver or use a company GIT for wordpress websites.

Local server with htdocs:
We can go to:

[**localIP**]/wordpresswebsite

And view the website, we can also make changes to the code and save it to the server, when we're done with the website we can upload it to the live-envoirement.

OR

Use a bussiness git server, where we store our projects.
Pull -> modify website -> push and the website is up to date.

Then the other person can Pull -> modify website -> push and now he changed the website.

What would you recommend for working together on websites?

Comment: Source control is a de-facto good practice in the software development community, so I would definitely suggest using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should definitely use Git for any kind of collaborative project.

It will allow you to easily see **who** contributed with **what** and **when**. Plus, you'll have the opportunity to easily restore a previous version if things go wrong.

Source control is such a valuable tool, it's highly recommended to invest a little time to set it up and use it properly. This will save you and your team a lot of headaches later.